# Sequelize default id type

Tags: node.js, model, default, sequelize.js

I would like to change automatically the id type for all tables for this definition :

```
id : {
  type : DataTypes.BIGINT.UNSIGNED,
  autoIncrement : true,
  primaryKey : true
}
```

In the [Sequelize doc](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/usage#block-4-line-53) there are options for general purposes.

But nothing on the default attributes, or on custom attributes to pass to every tables.
Any idea ?

Comment: It's not currently to generally modify the default attributes like that, but it's always possible to overwrite then on a per model basis.

Comment: OK and with a class method ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: I was thinking about a method class which will insert a custom attribute. Since we can create custom methods class generally, I thought it was a way to do it...